# Functional Programing; using streams to create a set/ list of objects in java

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

the object of this specific function is to create a list of (competitor objects ) Using 2 lists containing time and names.

note that this is a trail to convert from object oriented to functional programing , so its actually a record rather than an object.

my initial trial using a sort of recursion

```
public static List<Competitors> makeObjects(int[] time, String[] name){
        if (counter > name.length){
            return racers;
        }else{
            Competitors racer= new Competitors(name[counter],backToTime(time[counter]));
            racers.add(racer);
            return makeObjects(++counter,racers,time,name);
        }
```

and my try after discovering i can use streams

```
public static List<Competitors> makeObjects(int[] time, String[] name){
        List<Competitors> racers = new ArrayList<Competitors>();
        IntStream.range(0,time.length).mapToObj(i-> ).collect(new Competitors(name[i] ,backToTime(time[i])))
    }
```

Comment: If you've got two separate lists that aren't combined in any way, then I think you'll bend over backwards trying to make a stream more readable than a vanilla for loop.

Comment: `IntStream.range(0,time.length).mapToObj(i-> new Competitors(name[i] ,backToTime(time[i]))).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second approach, `makeObjects()`, is the functional approach.

Where you go wrong is that you are creating the `Competitor` objects in the wrong place; you map each `i` to a new Competitor. Then in the `collect()` call, you specify what type of collection. In your case, it would be `Collectors.toList()` or `Collectors.toSet()`. There is no need to create an  `ArrayList`; just assign the `IntStream...` to `List<Competitor> racers`.

Note that you should probably guard this method by first asserting that the arrays are the same length.

Also note that your class should be named `Competitor`, not `Competitors`; and `makeObjects` would be more descriptive as `createCompetitorsList`.